# call_user_func_array not break when it raise an exception

Tags: php, laravel

Here`s the code (a small piece in Laravel):

```
foreach ($this->getListeners($event) as $listener) {

    $response = call_user_func_array($listener, $payload);

    Log::debug(var_export($response, true));

    ...
}
```

when I add try catch block around the `call_user_func_array`, I can catch the exception, but when I remove it, the exception is gone, and $response = TRUE;
  I need to process the exception in `set_exception_handler`, can anyone tell me why ?

Note: PHP 5.6, Laravel 5.2

Comment: what do you want to $response to be? you can simply add $response = false to your catch block if that's of any help.

Comment: It might have something to do with the `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` It has     `protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    ];`

Comment: I tried that, but it won't get there, I can get the log after `call_user_func_array` is called, the exception seems gone.

Comment: Are you sure that exception really "disappears" (doesn't break your code) when you remove `try catch`? Maybe `var_export($response…` simply outputs `$response` **from the next entrance into this code, which is caused by some outer code**?

Comment: Try putting another `try...catch` around the whole foreach loop (to ensure that exception that isn't caught within the iteration itself, really breaks the loop).

Comment: You are right, @Sasha, Thanks, I'll keep tracking where the exception was processed.

Comment: Oh, I know why, it's my fault, thank you very much.@Sasha

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to break it yourself on an error.

From [call_user_func_array docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

> Returns the return value of the callback, or FALSE on error.

To process the error you can simply do:

```
foreach ($this->getListeners($event) as $listener) {

    $response = call_user_func_array($listener, $payload);

    if($response === false) {
        // do something on error
        break;
    }
}
```